# Transforming a TreeView to Multiple ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, treeview

Given a hierarchical data structure of the form:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyData> SubNodes { get; set; } 
}
```

I would like to display a series of ListBoxes representing that structure. The flow should be left --> right (e.g. like OS X's Finder), where the left-most ListBox contains the root nodes and the right-most the children.

Multiple items in each ListBox should be selectable, causing the available items in subsequent ListBoxes to update. This is trivial to do with a bit of LINQ and a hard-coded number of ListBoxes, however I wanted the template to be dynamic (i.e. ListBoxes should be added and removed depending on the availability of items). I'd also like the solution to be MVVM-compatible.

This type of control might be something that is already bundled in WPF, however I'm not sure what to search for! Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to use LINQ (or any C# code at all!) to set the ItemSource on the next ListBox. You can use WPF databinding for this:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourDataCollection}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listbox1, Path=SelectedItem.SubNodes}" />
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox3" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listbox2, Path=SelectedItem.SubNodes}" />
```

Basically you are binding the next listbox to the previous listbox's SelectedItem's SubNodes (you probably should make sure that the listbox can only select one at a time)

Now to hide the listboxes that do not have any items, you could use a IValueConverter to convert the object to a Visibility state. To do this, create a class:

```
public class ObjectToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And add some more data binding to your listboxes:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ObjectToVisibilityConverter x:Key="objectToVisible" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mw1, Path=dataCollection}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listbox1, Path=SelectedItem.SubNodes}" 
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listbox2, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource objectToVisible}}" />
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox3" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listbox2, Path=SelectedItem.SubNodes}" 
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listbox3, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource objectToVisible}}" />
</Grid>
```

Make sure to add your namespace to the window, so the valueconverter can actually be found, in my case I added this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Now this solution works only for a fixed amount of listboxes, but it does not rely on any C# code, aside from the valueconverter. Do you really have no idea about how many sublevels you might need? You could use this technique to add dozens of listboxes to a scrollview for example. 
To actually make this dynamic in a UserControl might become quite painful as there would be significant amount of code involved to add listboxes, set their items, delete or hide listboxes when a different root node is selected.

Another possibility might be creating a HierarchicalDataTemplate for the TreeView to customize the look of the treeview. This has the advantage of keeping the treeview, as it is the most useful control for hierarchical data, but changing it's looks should be entirely possible with WPF and it's templates. You might need to change the treeview's controltemplate though (I recommend Blend for editing any type of WPF template)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how many sub-levels there will be. I'm fetching the relationships from a self-referencing table in a SQL Server DB. As you say, a fixed number of sublevels is perfectly doable. Generalising to n is the tricky bit!

Comment: Also, I'd need to use LINQ to support multi-select functionality (to .Concat() subnodes of selected items)

Comment: From your question it was not clear that you are getting subnodes from the database upon selection. You can start by creating a UserControl that has a StackPanel (with a horizontal orientation), give it a x:Name and you can reference it from code. So you create a new ListBox object in your code, add it to the stackpanel by doing myStackPanel.Children.Add(myListBoxObject)
If you keep references to all the ListBox objects you create in a collection you can always remove them from the stackpanel later on